# Angular 2 ngModel not working ( javascript only )

Tags: javascript, angular

So I'm a newbie on Angular2(javascript) and I was able to make a simple "Hello world" with the angular 5 min tutorial. And I was curious of the new changes on Angular2 I start reading the Angular2 Js docs but I found that it was incomplete(sucks), so I started playing around, and I got stuck on two way binding. It always returns undefined

My current script:

```
( function(app) { 
  app.TestComponent =
    ng.core.Component({
      selector: 'test-comp',
      template: '<input ([ngModel])="name"><input type="button" (click)="click()" value="click">'
    }).Class({
      constructor: function(){},
      click: function(){ console.log(this.name) }
    })
})

(function(app) {                                                                                                                                
   app.AppModule =                                                                                                                                
     ng.core.NgModule({                                                                                                                           
       imports: [                                                                                                                                 
         ng.platformBrowser.BrowserModule                                                                                                         
       ],
       declarations: [ app.TestComponent ],                                     
       bootstrap: [ app.TestComponent ]                                                                  
     })                                                                                                                                           
     .Class({                                                                                                                                     
       constructor: function() {}                                                                                                                 
     });                                                                                                                                          
})(window.app || ( window.app = {} ));
```

Whats puzzling me is there are no errors. Which makes it more difficult to Identify whats causing the undefined. Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to be

```
[(ngModel)]
```

not

```
([ngModel])
```

It's called banana in a box for a reason ;-)

Comment: Okay now I got this error "Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input". Any Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You need to add `FormsModule` to the module imports

Comment: FormsModule fixed it! Thanks, Have a great day :)