# ngModel in ng-template dialog

Tags: angular, angular5, ngx-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap-modal

In my Angular 5 controller HTML I've got a simple `ng-template` that has a form in it, and the `input` elements have an `ngModel` binding.  The modal form for that template is just displayed via a button event like so:

```js
openModal(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template);
}
```

When I click a button on the form, and it calls my `(click)` handler, I'm not sure how to access those bound values as they don't seem to bind to the current controller.

So the template has something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="ar" id="ar" class="form-control" ([ngModel])="ar" required>
```

But `this.ar` is always undefined in the controller.

Comment: Replace `([ngModel])` with `[(ngModel)]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 ngModel not working ( javascript only )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40278606/angular-2-ngmodel-not-working-javascript-only)

Comment: That was it.  Helps if I don't have a typo in the variable name ;)  Thanks.